# jQuery animate "display: none"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem creating a smooth transition/animation using jQuery. Been busy with this for a while now, tried googling it.

I have a page with 4 tiles, if a tile is selected (like it already is in the example), all the tiles "close" and a div next to the selected tile becomes visible, the div `content_container`. The tiles are made out of `class="tile"` and if closed `class="tile closed"`. When i hover over a tile, it expands to it's original form.

When clicked on a tile, the content_container should close again and the tiles should expand back to their original forms before redirecting to selected URL. The tiles work good, however I'm having trouble with the content_container. I tried to animate close it by setting `transition` rules in css and on click changing the `width=0` and `height=0` of the div. However it seems to ignore it/staying the same width. Then I tried to set `display: none`. Which works, but it doesn't animate it, the content_container just **disappears** which is not the desired effect.

Using google I found an answer which said to first animate `opacity: 0` before setting `display: none`. This is not a solution to my problem, because it will still take up all the space, while the tiles also expand, making the two right tiles fall off screen.

Does anybody know how to animate display none? And/or why is it ignoring `width = 0`, because if that works it should also animate it right?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RE5hF/10/

Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT 1

I think the simple solution would be to just change the width, so I've tried to use this:

```
$("#container").on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.not_hidden').css({"width":"0px !important"});
    $('.content_container').css({"width":"0px !important"});
});
```

But on click the code just gets completely ignored, if I put some other code in it like `$('.tile').removeClass('closed');` the tile's class does change, so the 'click function' is working. Just changing the width on the containers doesn't work. Can't seem to find out why.

---

### EDIT 2

FIXED

Code was conflicting with `.hover()` code, width was changing of the container but immediately set back to different width because of the `hover()` code. Ended up adding another class for the `content_container`, put it in the `hover code` and use `.remove()` to remove the class on click of `a`. This way the `.content_container.css('width':'0px')` wasn't conflicting with the `.hover()` code anymore.

working: http://jsfiddle.net/RE5hF/14/

Comment: Sorry, title was incorrect, edited it just now

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand your question, but I think you want to animate hiding an element.

For that, you can use

```
.fadeOut()
```

or

```
.hide('fadein');
```

or

```
.slideOut();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's got the same problem as the 'opacity:0' solution, it's taking up space while fade-ing out, which I don't want. I need it to "collapse"

Comment: Not working for me, still just disappears http://jsfiddle.net/RE5hF/11/  doesn't slide or anything. Thanks for the effort though!